# how to call angular 1.5 component on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

As i am a newbie in Typescript i am fail to get answer that how to call my angular component "summaryReport "on button click, here is my demo code.let say i have a button that has to call my component on openPdf() click,

```
<md-button ng-click="$ctrl.openPdf()">Summary Report</md-button>

My Component code is,

namespace mitchell.audit.estimate {
export class SummaryReportComponent {
    static ngComponentName = 'summaryReport';
}
angular.module(ngModuleName)
    .component(SummaryReportComponent.ngComponentName, {
        bindings: {
            estimateId: '@',
        },
        templateUrl: 'src/app/estimate/pdfReport/pdfSummary-report.component.html',
        controller: PdfSummaryReportController
    });
```

}
and I want to call My Component template,

```
<summary-report flex layout="column" estimate-id="$ctrl.estimateId" style="display:none;"></summary-report>
```

I also tried calling this component template by putting "" in a HTML file which will be load on button click but this is also not working. Please help me out to find the proper way or solution to click my component template on button click.
Thanks Manisha

Comment: can any one please reply

Comment: i am not getting why none of expert even replied

Answer (score 0):

You can use $compile to load your component